# Signle click to Create folders and Spring controller,service, dao, model, view inside those folders while using Eclipse, Spring, Java

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I am working on Spring project using Eclipse IDE. It takes me good amount of time to create Controller, Service, ServiceImpl, Dao, DaoImpl, Model and View folders every time inside the project. This is repeated work.

As creating those are same all the time, is there any way to create the folder structure and the required MVC related classes inside the folders easily?
I think there is not any way. In that case, how to proceed if I want to develop this facility in my project? I mean, I want to develop facility using what I will be able to create Controller, Service, ServiceImpl, Dao, DaoImpl, Model and View Folders & Classes in quick time.

Comment: Each of those classes is going to be different for each project; how exactly do you expect a tool to know what to create? (If you use Spring Data, by the way, you don't have to write DAO implementations.)

Comment: It would create Classes with given names, apply some specific annotations. In a project you need multiple Controller, Service, Dao classes. It would be lot easier if you just apply some names of the classes and those will be created with assigned annotations. Then you dont need to create those manually multiple times.